# facebook api: using ajax or javascript POST instead of curl -F

Tags: ajax, facebook-graph-api

i don't plan to use the facebook sdk. Instead i;d like to use the graph api to post to user's feed. As mentioned somewhere in the facebook developer documentation, there is this example:

curl-F 'access_token =...' \ -F 'message = Hello, Arjun. I like this new API. '\ https: / / graph.facebook.com / Arjun / feed

It worked for me when i replaced "Arjun" with the uid of my target user. Now I wanted to achieve the same functionality using ajax instead of using curl. How do I do that? It doesnt look like simple POST works. I tried the following in my javascript but didnt work

```
  var dataString = 'message=hello&access_token=<acccess_token>';
  $.ajax(
     type: "POST",
     url: "https://graph.facebook.com/<uid>/feed",
     data:dataString,
     success: function() {
         alert("sucess");
     }
  });
```

please suggest

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Since cross domain ajax call are not allowed this cannot be done as you have mentioned.
You will need to use Facebook Javascript sdk http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/